# How do I store the result of a comparison in Prolog and use it later?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

Say I want to write an (admittedly unnecessary, but it's an example) predicate that compares two values, and returns the result as a variable that can be referenced, something like this:

```
compare(Value1, Value2, Result) :- 
    Result is Value1 > Value2.
```

But in [Swish](http://swish.swi-prolog.org) I get an error:

```
src:2: Syntax error: Operator priority clash
compare/3: Domain error: `order' expected, found `'5''
```

After I have `Result`, how would I then use its value in another predicate? Would it be possible to say:

```
compare(5, 2, Result),
Result.
```

Or am I completely misunderstanding the philosophy of Prolog?

Comment: You're trying to use prolog like it computes results. It generally doesn't work that way. It's more about "unification" of terms. It's a very different concept than both imperative and functional languages. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: What did you expect to be saved in `Result`? `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Superficially, it's a problem of operators' precedence: this compiles

```
compare(Value1, Value2, R) :- R is (Value1 > Value2).
```

but it doesn't run:

```
?- compare(1,3,X).
ERROR: compare/3: Type error: `atom' expected, found `1' (an integer)
```

You're going to clash with a builtin, see [compare](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3)/3.
Better to avoid, although in SWI-Prolog [redefine_system_predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=redefine_system_predicate/1)/1 directive could help.

[is](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2)/2 is a *predicate* implementing a small (?) functional sublanguage, evaluating right side arithmetic expression, while [>](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3E%29/2)/2 implements the comparison after evaluating both sides. What I mean:

```
..., A > B, ...
```

it's either true or false, doesn't *yields* a number...

Maybe you want

```
my_compare(A,B,C) :- A > B -> C = 1 ; A < B -> C = -1 ; C = 0.
```

*edit*:

I think I should illustrate how to *store* the comparison value: just instance the result and call it later.

```
my_compare(A,B,C) :- A > B -> C = true ; C = false.
```

then

```
?- my_compare(1,3,R), (R -> writeln('comparison succeeded') ; writeln('comparison failed')).
```

Comment: @WillNess: done, thanks. I cannot recall why I deleted it. There was a bug ?

Comment: yes, in how you generated the output. It said "norwegian". no biggie. :) also, names of smokes were different.